# how to align text of text view to right side and also text should be in center of text view

Tags: android-layout

I want to align my text in text view to right side and also it should be centered in the text view.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:gravity="right">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/img_campaign"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">

    </ImageView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_campaign"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Dummy TEXT Dummy TEXT "
        android:textSize="20dp">

    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you explain with your screen what you want ? as from your question it's difficult to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As you have only applied `android:gravity="right"` in your `Text View`. If you want it`Right with Center` in `Text View` then you need to change it to  `android:gravity="right|center_vertical"` in your `Text View`.

This `android:gravity="right|center_vertical"` will `Center` your Text's in `Text View`.

**Follow this.**

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_campaign"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Dummy TEXT Dummy TEXT "
        android:textSize="20dp">
    </TextView>
```

Comment: @praneetk2 Glad to help you ! :) .Accept the answer Check mark this as right answer  just left of answer. i think you know how to do it.

Comment: @praneetk2 Accept the answer :) as it's solved your problem. check mark as correct.

Comment: @praneetk2 Thanks glad to help you :).